# Angular: How to get default @Input value?

Tags: javascript, angular

We are developing components and when using them, we would like to use the same mechanism like for DOM nodes to conditionally define attributes. So for preventing attributes to show up at all, we set the value to null and its not existing in the final HTML output. Great!

```
<button [attr.disabled]="condition ? true : null"></button>
```

Now, when using our own components, this does not work. When we set `null`, we actually get `null` in the components @Input as the value. Any by default set value will be overwritten.

```
...
@Component({
    selector: 'myElement',
    templateUrl: './my-element.component.html'
})

export class MyElementComponent {
    @Input() type: string = 'default';
...
```

```
<myElment [type]="condition ? 'something' : null"></myElement>
```

So, whenever we read the `type` in the component, we get `null` instead of the `'default'` value which was set.

I tried to find a way to get the original default value, but did not find it. It is existing in the `ngBaseDef` when accessed in `constructor` time, but this is not working in production. I expected `ngOnChanges` to give me the real (default) value in the first change that is done and therefore be able to prevent that `null` is set, but the `previousValue` is `undefined`.

We came up with some ways to solve this:

- defining a `default` object and setting for every input the default value when its `null`
- addressing the DOM element in the template again, instead of setting null

```
<myElement #myelem [type]="condition ? 'something' : myelem.type"></myElement>
```

- defining set / get for every input to prevent null setting

```
_type: string = 'default';
@Input()
set type(v: string) {if (v !== null) this._type = v;}
get type() { return this._type; }
```

but are curious, if there are maybe others who have similar issues and how it got fixed. Also I would appreciate any other idea which is maybe more elegant.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35839120/how-to-set-default-parameter-for-input-in-angular2  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36071942/how-to-set-default-values-for-angular-2-component-properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no standard angular way, because many times you would want `null` or `undefined` as value. Your ideas are not bad solutions. I got a couple more

1. I suppose you can also use the `ngOnChanges` hook for this:

```
@Input()
type: string = 'defaultType';

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
 // == null to also match undefined
 if (this.type == null) {
    this.type = 'defaultType';
  }
}
```

2. Or using `Observables`:

```
private readonly _type$ = new BehaviorSubject('defaultType');

readonly type$ = this._type$.pipe(
  map((type) => type == null ? 'defaultType' : type)
); 

@Input()
set type(type: string) {
  this._type$.next(type);
}
```

3. Or create your own decorator [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true&emitDecoratorMetadata=true&ssl=24&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEQKbAIYgDZQBQBuG2IqAXIhmAJ4CUiA3gFCKIBOqUIbSoksCPFAxsA5pwpVqAGkQBrVNQoBnKGxhhRiAD6Jl1ALYAjONnrNWrCAlWIiJVAEEIEVMuVw2iALyIA5AD6AX6IANTyigB0UHAAymoaonj04YHBANxMLJYA8kYAVqjQkQAm6BqoAApscAAOqGxQ1EIi4lCyCjKM2ZaIbRR80PBIyd29vRxcPIhQABYwygDa9qTOru6eALqIAIS+YDjYiAD8M-NLK04ubh5s2xSXPZYAvtJPrMoSiIMCI2CoAA8oOZ3pYYMBEHgdnlCsVajUYk16pFZhhlDkAO5gap1BpNSIQYjYITnWSXNY3Ty0EHjcYwopQUrlf44+qNZpzBZk4ira4bNiyCy08YY9TCIzYcgzNikN7C8aoA4GBoYCVSzDYT5y+WWaxgYAwUTcVWSihqUig3rPWiZeXPLLyzkXHlXda3bb7QFQW3jV6gxUgZVsE1S82obW9PUGo3BtVmmXhp7Wn3PTL2pgQbBo5SIAAqblgmjGiAAAmhMDh8ABGWjZKAF44UJVGBqZbJ61Qy6CeIQNpuBltsGmWJ3RAs+GYFlNMdMdqCT1RVif-DF5guJPAAJhtGZs8-rqk3y9Qq-zqg3O7nC6gAGZj6f15o8ABWHdMA+3se2Xybqs3tsdqYqCRNgcBJB+VZfu016blBsgfjeUFvsAniQleGCIBo141sW4KQhgkSqCIUDKAA6jAcx4GkfjUsWVg2EBIFgXgGA7qw9r2kAA)

```
function Default(value: any) {
  return function(target: any, key: string | symbol) {
    const valueAccessor = '__' + key.toString() + '__';

    Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
      get: function () {
        return this[valueAccessor] != null ? this[valueAccessor] : value
      },
      set: function (next) {
        if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this, valueAccessor)) {
          Object.defineProperty(this, valueAccessor, {
            writable: true,
            enumerable: false
          });
        }

        this[valueAccessor] = next;
      },
      enumerable: true
    });
  };
}
```

which you can use like this:

```
@Input()
@Default('defaultType')
type!: string;
```

Comment: The third solution looks very promising. Unfortunatelly it is not working as soon you have a component more than one time. All components will receive the same type set from outside, even if some or one got null he will get the type from the other component. As this looks the most promising I will look further into it and see where is ( i made ) the mistake :) Thanks!

Comment: @Fabian I should not have posted untested code :) anyways, I've updated my answer. We obviously need to use a value accessor property, so that it's different for every instance.

Comment: I got already a working version together by myself, thanks a lot for the update. Now it works like a charm! ;) Thank you for the idea of creating own decorators.

Comment: @Fabian You're welcome :) how did you manage to make it work for multiple class instances?

Comment: @Fabian I've updated my answer a bit from the decorator, because I noticed that in a `for .. in` loop it would show the value accessor property as well. By declaring it directly in the `this.set` and setting enumerable to false it won't show up anymore.

Comment: I took the decorator approach, check my [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/default-value-decorator) with decorator tests

Comment: @Nexaddo your decorator will fail when you have two components with different values. I've forked your stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/default-value-decorator-mbyhgi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). As you can see, the undefined gets overwritten with the set value of the 2nd component. I first had it like you had, but had to change it to use a hidden `valueAccessor` value :)

Comment: You're correct, the issue seems to be due to the fact that property decorators get initialised only once per the entire app and not per class. 

so the `val` variable in the decorator will hold only the last changed value.

We need the class to hold the value for this to work.

Thank you for the feedback @PoulKruijt, I updated my [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/default-value-decorator) with a new test to check for this issue

Answer (score 0):

Just one more option (perhaps simpler if you don't want to implement your own custom @annotation) based off Poul Krujit solution:

```
const DEFAULT_VALUE = 'default';
export class MyElementComponent {
  typeWrapped = DEFAULT_VALUE;

  @Input()
  set type(selected: string) {
    // this makes sure only truthy values get assigned
    // so [type]="null" or [type]="undefined" still go to the default.
    if (selected) {
      this.typeWrapped = selected;
    } else {
      this.typeWrapped = DEFAULT_VALUE;
    }
  }
  get type() {
    return this.typeWrapped;
  }
}
```

Comment: the issue with this, if you first have a value on the input, and then set this value to `null` or `undefined` it won't change the `typeWrapped` property, and your default value is gone.

Comment: I've updated my proposal to include that case.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to do this for multiple inputs, you can also use a custom `pipe` instead of manually defining the getter/setter and default for each input. The `pipe` can contain the logic and defaultArg to return the defaultArg if the input is `null`.

i.e.

```js
// pipe
@Pipe({name: 'ifNotNullElse'})
export class IfNotNullElsePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, defaultVal?: string): string {
    return value !== null ? value : defaultVal;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- myElem template -->
<p>Type Input: {{ type | ifNotNullElse: 'default' }}</p>

<p>Another Input: {{ anotherType | ifNotNullElse: 'anotherDefault' }}</p>
```